# Is visareservation.com scam?

Tags: schengen-visas

Schengen Visa rule makers suggest applicants to reserve flights instead of actually buying tickets. They also suggest applicants to use https://visareservation.com/ as you can read here https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/flight-itinerary-visa-application/#reserve-flight-ticket-without-payment

I did some research and some people consider visareservation a scam: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskEurope/comments/bjbaf7/unable_to_get_schengen_visa_appointment_before/em74s5j/

Is it a scam?

I was hoping to use it for my flight and hotel reservations since the official website recommends it.

Comment: schengenvisainfo.com aren't the "rule makers", it's a third-party commercial advice site, and is not "official" in any way. It's very likely that visareservation.com pays schengenvisainfo.com for being listed.

Comment: The actual official site is https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy_en (note it's .eu, not .com).

Comment: https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/about-us/: "We are also not affiliated with the EU or any official agency."

Comment: It looks like you have made two different accounts, likely by accident. Please get them merged.

Answer (score 4):

"schengenvisainfo.com" is not the "rule makers", instead it is a site with resources for reserving/buying tickets and useful links. Neither it is an official government site nor a ticket buying platform.

As you said, [they](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/flight-itinerary-visa-application/#reserve-flight-ticket-without-payment) linking applicants to use the "visareservation.com" website was more likely a [advertisement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay-per-click) or a [referral link](https://www.seobility.net/en/wiki/Referral_Link) by "schengenvisainfo.com"  or a link that was added for general usage not "suggesting" (at least from a authority standpoint).

The official web page for the Schengen Area is [this](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy_en). Notice this message at the left-above corner of the webpage:

[image]

It ends with europa.eu not .com or .info.

---

[www.schengenvisainfo.com](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com) has advertisements and links to other sites and is a more resources and blog website rather than a official "rule-maker" website. [be](https://blog.trendmicro.com/ads-on-websites-are-dangerous-to-more-than-your-sanity/) [cautionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Phishing&oldid=1044370260) when using these types of sites.